# Get number of returned rows mysqli php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have been trying to solve this for some time. I'm tiring to echo the number of returned rows from the mysql query,

```
$linkTow  = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$getVotesSQL = "SELECT null FROM votes WHERE `idgame` = ?";
$getVotesStmt = $linkTow->prepare($getVotesSQL);
$getVotesStmt->bind_param("s", $idGame);
$getVotesStmt->execute();
echo $getVotesStmt->num_rows;
$getVotesStmt->close();
$linkTow->close();
```

I always get 0.

Comment: how about you output the rows returned from the query

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php read the manual stop being lazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really prefer using `$linkTow->prepare` then this is the proper way to do it:

```
$getVotesSQL = "SELECT null FROM votes WHERE `idgame` = ?";
$getVotesStmt = $linkTow->prepare($getVotesSQL);
$getVotesStmt->bind_param("s", $idGame);
$getVotesStmt->execute();
$getVotesStmt->store_result(); // <- IMPORTANT
echo $getVotesStmt->num_rows;
$getVotesStmt->close();
$linkTow->close();
```

What you are doing before is for `$linkTow->query`

> **MANUAL**

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php

Comment: Thanks I didn't add store_result();

Comment: Is there a better way than $linkTow->prepare?